# Posicion botones footer pagina

Tags: css

Puse dos botones en el fondo de mi pagina, la intención es que siempre estén visibles y abajo del todo, pero quiero uno que ocupe el 50% de la parte izquierda y otro el 50% restante a la derecha, ahora mismo se me superponen.

```css
.boton1cn{
    position:fixed;
    width:50%;
    height:40px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    background-color:#4762a8;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  z-index:100;
}

.boton2cn{
    position:fixed;
    width:50%;
    height:40px;
    bottom:0px;
    right:0px;
    background-color:#4762a8;
    color:#FFF;
    text-align:center;
  font-size:20px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  z-index:100;
}

.my-float{
    margin-top:16px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<a href="#" class="boton1cn" target="_blank">
<i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"> Contáctanos por Whatsapp</i>
</a>
<a href="#" class="boton2cn" target="_blank">
<i class="fa fa-phone my-float"> ¡Llámanos!</i>
</a>
```

¿Como debería de quedar?

Gracias.

Comment: Al que quieras que este a la izquierda le tendrás que cambiarle la propiedad `right` y ponerle `right: 50%;`. Si te vale esto comentamelo y te lo pongo como respuesta.

Comment: David, si la respuesta de @Rabegi ha solucionado tu duda, te invito a aceptarla y marcarla como útil. De esta manera ambos ganarán reputación y servirá de referencia para futuros visitantes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que ambos tienen la propiedad `right` a 0, por lo tanto ambos están posicionándose a la derecha del todo, quedando uno por encima del otro.

Para solucionarlo, uno de los dos (el que quieras en la izquierda), debería cambiar ese `right` por un `left` (En este caso yo se lo he puesto a `.boton1cn`, pero si lo quieres en el otro sería cambiar un lado por otro.

De paso he refactorizado un poco, creando una clase para las propiedades comunes de los botones, de esta forma no duplicas código y si quieres hacer una modificación que afecte a ambos solo tienes que cambiarlo una vez :)

**Edit**: 
Se le añade un `padding` de 10px tanto arriba como abajo (0 hacia los lados porque el texto ya está centrado) y, añadiendo la propiedad `box-sizing: border-box`, conseguimos que el tamaño que le damos al contenedor (`width` y `height`) sea el total sumando `padding` y `border`.

Es decir, sumando los 10px de arriba + 10px de abajo + ? = 40px totales, siendo ? el tamaño que dedicará al contenido (el texto en este caso).

Así podemos centrar fácilmente el contenido en este caso. (Ya que se ha hecho así, no haría falta indicarle que el `i` debe tener un margen superior).

```css
.boton {
  position: fixed;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  background-color: #4762a8;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #999;
  z-index: 100;
}

.boton1cn{
  left: 0;
}

.boton2cn{
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<a href="#" class="boton boton1cn" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"> Contáctanos por Whatsapp</i>
</a>
<a href="#" class="boton boton2cn" target="_blank">
  <i class="fa fa-phone my-float"> ¡Llámanos!</i>
</a>
```

Comment: Perfecto! Mil gracias!

Comment: Como había leído un comentario sobre centrarlo verticalmente, he editado con una forma de hacerlo. Al parecer el comentario se ha borrado pero dejo la respuesta editada por le sirviera a alguien :)